# Meaning of schon in "das schaff' ich schon"

Tags: translation, meaning, expression, modal-particle

Watching Futurama, one of the characters said:

> "das schaff' ich schon!"

What exactly does this mean, and how does "schon" change the meaning?

(*I don't remember, but I think it was Fry, which makes me think it's something that kids say to their parents when they don't want help!*)

Comment: Good question! I have no idea how to describe this. There also is no direct translation. Interested to see what people come up with

Comment: *Schon* typically translates to *already*, and though I think this particular idiomatic use that has existed in German for ages didn't used to exist in English, I am actually seeing it quite often recently. Example: "You can do that already." Here, *schon/already* expresses confidence in the face of reason for pessimism.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've already described the meaning quite accurately - think of a situation where someone's facing a difficult situation or task, and other people doubt whether he or she will handle it. To express his/her (self-)confidence that the result will be positive, one could say

> „Das schaffe ich schon!“ / „Das schaffst Du schon!“ / „Das schaffen wir schon!“

"Schon" may convey different meanings. The german "[Duden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duden)" [enumerates the most important ones](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schon_gewiss_blosz_noch). In your example, it would be #4 - expressing confidence, often in reply to doubts expressed by someone else.

As translation I would propose:

> "I can handle it" / "I can manage it"

I think using "can" is stronger than "will" - as an attempt to catch the meaning of the "schon".

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, so I think of it rather literally, like a white lie: I say "I'm already handling it!" so that you don't doubt me, even though I'm not actually handling it yet.  Is that sort of how native speakers think of it?

Answer (score 7):

The 'schon' in this position is a modal particle, expressing the speakers need to soothe themselves or the person adressed.

Das schaffe ich. = I'll make it. (stating a fact)
Das schaffe ich schon. = I'll make it, don't worry. (reassuring)

Lookup wikipedia for mor info on modal particles: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_modal_particle

Answer (score 3):

> I can do this for sure!

The "schon" emphasizes the anger of anyone doubting that. It's very colloquial.

Synonyms are

> Das packe ich schon!